# Which streaming media formats allow you to easily (sloppily) chop a part of the feed and save it as a valid file?

Tags: video, video-streaming, streaming, video-capture

I'm not a codec programmer, but have a need to chop media streams into multiple individual parts. Since video formats that support streaming allow *some* corruption of data, I'm hopeful such formats allow me to simply save a segment (e.g. 5 minutes) of the stream (or of a larger file of the same format) starting at an arbitrary byte offset, provided I first prepend it with some fixed, but format-specific header. A few seconds of noise / lossiness on playback at the beginning of the chopped segment would be OK. This way, I wouldn't need to know much about the underlying file format: would just need to know which fixed header to use to prepend the chopped "segment" with, one per video format type. So to be clear this would not be the "right" / ideal way to chop the stream into parts: more like a quick and dirty way.

A high level view of [Matroska](https://www.matroska.org/technical/streaming.html) for example, seems promising. Of the standard (known) [video formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats) which would support this approach? If this approach is a thing, has anyone gathered this cross-format header information in one place? (I've been browsing some FOSS projects, but so far no cigar.)

Thanks in advance,

Babak

Answer (score 2):

Matroska/MKV/WebM is pretty easy for this, but there are a couple steps:

1. When the stream starts, save all the data up before the first cluster element, and treat that as initialization data.  Any time you drop into the stream later, you must reinsert this data at the beginning.
2. You can seek to cluster elements, but you must align these so that you start a cluster after that initialization data from step 1, before you send that data off to the demuxer.
3. Clusters *must* begin with a keyframe if you want web compatibility.  Not all encoder produce streams like this, so make sure yours is configured to do so.

An alternative is to use MPEG-TS.  Most anything that can play TS can also synchronize to it automatically.  You don't need any extra header information, as everything is inside the stream itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Brad—and apologies for not ack'ing sooner. That's not too onerous with Matroska/MKV/WebM.